# Get the author name from the Guardian open platform

Tags: android, api

I am writing a query to retrieve the author name of the articles? what shall I write in the api link to get it. 
I used the one that send by email, but it does not show the author name 
https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=****

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://open-platform.theguardian.com/documentation/), the `search` endpoint does not provide author information, so my guess is that you'll need to obtain that information from the content endpoints.

Answer (score 5):

I read the documentation again, and I found that I have to use the show-tags=contributor to get the authors
so the url link will be

https://content.guardianapis.com/search?&show-tags=contributor&api-key=test